# What's wrong with using Excel Concatenation as following?

Tags: excel-formula

Could someone please tell me what's wrong with this formula ?

```
=CONCATENATE(=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1),"GroupFolder\fileName.png")
```

Why doesn't the concatenation formula accept the first argument to be an input even though it returns a string?

I'm trying to get the path of a certain file inside the directory of the excel document.

Comment: remove the second `=`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't notice the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with this except a minor typo. Just remove the `=` sign before the `LEFT` function. In addition, please take note that `CELL` function will return nothing if your worksheet is unsaved. So, save your worksheet first.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1),"GroupFolder\fileName.png")
```

Hope this helps..